# Why this message "placeholder-shown is not a valid pseudo class"?

Tags: label, floating

I have an Angular-Dot net core project in VISUAL STUDIO 2019. My floating label is ok but I can't use placeholder-shown. In my style.css, I have this message:

```
 placeholder-shown is not a valid pseudo class.
```

Some ideas?

Comment: Need to really see you html to have a shot at answering this.